# How to check part of file name and delete/replace the file in ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, antbuilder

How can I check part of file name from downloads and replace old file from target. 
Version is part of file name. If old version file not exist then simply copy it. Consider files in 'downloads' are latest.

Folder 'downloads' have latest file from server. And 'target' folder where some file are already there.

File name pattern: `<UNIQUE_NAME>_<VERSION>_<SOME-TYPE>.dat`

/**downloads** - All are latest in here

**FILE01**_01.02.03_xy-z.dat
**FILE02**_02.03.04_xy-z.dat
**FILE_11**_03.04.05_xy-z.dat

/**target** - before
**FILE02**_01.00.02_xy-z.dat
**FILE04**_01.00.00_xy-z.dat
**FILE_03**_01.00.01_xy-z.dat
**FILE_11**_01.01.00_xy-z.dat

/**target** - after movement (ToDo) 
**FILE01**_01.02.03_xy-z.dat - wasn't exist in target (simply copy)
**FILE02**_02.03.04_xy-z.dat - replaced by latest
**FILE04**_01.00.00_xy-z.dat - couldn't download latest (do nothing)
**FILE_03**_01.00.01_xy-z.dat - couldn't download latest (do nothing)
**FILE_11**_03.04.05_xy-z.dat - replaced by latest

Comment: If possible using <scriptdef> by javascript that also fine.

Comment: FILE_11_03.04.05_xy-z.dat        doesnt have the format <uniquename>_<version>_<sometype>

Comment: Thanks @Alan, Actually that's the constraint. Unique part of name can also contain '_'.

Comment: I think formula for getting unique name of file is: upto the char before underscore before version. Which means, char before (_) underscore before first (.) dot. As first dot will come in version and underscore before that is joiner of unique name and version.

Comment: This is the default behavior of Ant's `copy` task. An existing file in the destination dir will only be overwritten if it is older than the file in the source dir, unless you set the `overwrite` attribute to true, in which case all files will be overwritten regardless of their modification times. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Comment: Thanks @CAustin, But file name in destination is not same. Filename itself contains version. Only some part of file name is unique, that's in bold.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that part. Do you need to keep the file names as they are? This problem could be solved pretty easily by removing the version from everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add library for 'for loop'

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Update by iterating all files in downloads

```
<target name="update" depends="download" description="moves downloded dat files to projects dest">
    <for param="file" delimiter=";">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${downloads}" includes="*.dat" casesensitive="false" />
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <echo>file: @{file}</echo>
            <basename file="@{file}" property="filename" />
            <!--echo>filename: ${filename}</echo-->
            <propertyregex property="uniq" input="${filename}" regexp="^[^.]*(?=_)" select="\0" casesensitive="false" />
            <echo>uniq: ${uniq}</echo>
            <delete dir="${dest}" includes="${uniq}*" />
            <copy file="@{file}" tofile="${dest}/${filename}" />
            <var name="uniq" unset="true" />
            <var name="filename" unset="true" />
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```